# Animate width from left to right (with text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have text content with a 'wipe'-like transition, using jQuery to animate element width. This works fine when anchored to the left, as width is removed from the right side.

See fiddle for simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/4jz7e0dw/5/

You can see in the fiddle, that when aligned left (red) the text stays still and the width animation trims it back from the right. This is good.

However, I now need this to work when aligned to the right.

If I align everything right, the text stays anchored to the left of its element, and width is removed from the right (blue text block in fiddle). This results in a sliding effect rather than the static 'wipe' effect I want. This is not good.

If I align to the right but use `direction: rtl;` (like the green example), the 'wipe' effect works correctly, but the content of the elements is reversed. This is not good.

How can I have text right aligned and get the width to remove from the left (making the 'wipe' effect instead of a slide), without reversing the content order? Basically I need the same effect as when aligned to the left (red), but mirrored (without mirroring content elements).

Comment: the green block works as you want?

Comment: @Mohit No, you'll see the text content is reversed in the green block. The width animation effect works, but the content order needs to stay the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the desired effect using a flex-box display.

Here is the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/4jz7e0dw/11/

By using `direction: rtl` in combination with `flex-direction: row-reverse` in the child, the list keeps the original order of elements.

Comment: Legend. Why did I not think of flex?! Thanks. Now to see how this works on a 3-level deep ul list...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to put all of the content into a single `<li>` instead of seperate ones.

```
<div class="container slide-right rtl">
  <ul id="target3" class="slide">
  <li>CLICK THIS TO DEMO</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If for whatever reason you do need multiple items, another solution would be to simply reverse the order of the elements in your HTML

Comment: Cheers, though I need there to be numerous text elements as they need additional data attributes for other functionality, and they're added through a PHP loop. Even using spans inside a p element results in some weird behaviour with RTL. Reversing the HTML is the only solution I've found so far, though it's not ideal as the list is multi-tiered and I'm a fan of keeping the HTML clean and logical. Hopefully someone has a JS / CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
.slide {
...
unicode-bidi: plaintext;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4jz7e0dw/12/  -- what browser/version are you using?

Comment: Currently on iOS, tried Chrome & Safari, no change. How about you?

Comment: Did you visit the link in the comment? Mine overrides the `rtl` and displays CLICK THIS TO DEMO like normal

Comment: Yeah no change with your fiddle in the comments. What browser & OS are you using?

Comment: Chrome. I tried it on both windows 10 and Android phone. Weird

Answer (score 0):

I forked a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/am87yhp9/

Is this the effect you want to achieve?

Manipulating the Margin property, and changing the direction from rtl -> ltr.

JQ:

```
jQuery('.slide').click(function(){
    var width = this.clientWidth;
    $(this).animate({ 'width': 0, "marginRight": width}, 1500);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but no not what I was wanting to achieve; this effectively adds a left margin to the original left-aligned effect. I wanted the effect to be mirrored. Rbla3066 got it working nicely.